# When you're searching users, what are the tags that show under the user's reputation?

Tags: support, user-interface, user-information

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are the tags below my user name determined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113890/how-are-the-tags-below-my-user-name-determined)

When you're searching users, what are the tags that show under the user's reputation?

I've noticed some users have nothing in that place , and some others have various tags, what does it mean, and how is it controlled?

Comment: From what I can tell this seems to be related to the tags of questions asked. Looking for you for example, shows the tags "user-interface" and "user-information".

Comment: Ah: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113890/how-are-the-tags-below-my-user-name-determined