# How are Top Tags determined in case of ties in score?

Tags: support, tags, profile-page

Each user's profile page contains a [list of top tags](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/72119/glorfindel?tab=profile):

[image]

and the highest one is also shown in the [reputation widget](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/72119/glorfindel?tab=topactivity):

[image]

Those lists are determined by the total score of your answers in that tag. But I'm wondering what happens in case of ties? They happen quite often if you have only a single answer on a site.

(The tags below your name in the user list are determined by the [number of votes on both questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113890/how-are-the-tags-below-my-user-name-determined), so this is not a duplicate of the indicated question.)

In the links above from my Game Development profile, you can see it's not the most popular tag which is chosen (that would've been [physics]); from my [Stack Overflow en español profile](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/22845/glorfindel?tab=profile) it seems not to be alphabetically ordered either.