# How are users' tags determined?

Tags: support, tags, profile-page, users

I've looked at [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113890/how-are-the-tags-below-my-user-name-determined), but it's still not clear to me.

Searching https://stackoverflow.com/users/ my user tags are HTML, JavaScript and jQuery. This is the case for all filters (week, month, quarter, year, all). I have a famous question with these tags.
But the top tags on my profile page are C#, .NET and ASP.NET.

It doesn't make sense that the user tags are determined by a question, but should rather be based on my top tags and answers. As that more accurately reflects my strengths, whereas a famous question doesn't, it just shows that a lot of other people had the same question.

Can you please explain how these tags are determined?

Comment: Seeing that you don't have your SO account linked to your MSE account, it is hard for us to see what happened exactly. Please consider sharing a link to your SO profile.

Answer (score 6):

> Searching stackoverflow.com/users/ my user tags are html, JavaScript and jQuery. This is the case for all filters (week, month, quarter, year, all). I have a famous question with these tags.

Not only a famous question (that's about views); it also must get quite a few votes. According to the answer on the question you already linked to, these tags are the ones you

> earned the most votes in during this [period]

For this, **both questions and answers** are counted.

---

> But the top tags on my profile page are c#, .NET and asp.net.

Yes, because those are **solely based on answers**, not on questions.